# change the value of a key in existing schema json?

Tags: json, wordpress, schema

I have a plugin in WordPress, that generates html schema notation in application/ld+json format like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "JobPosting",
    "datePosted": "2023-11-30T00:00:00+01:00",
    "title": "Web developer",
    "description": "something",
    "hiringOrganization": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": ""
    },
    "identifier": {
        "@type": "PropertyValue",
        "name": "",
        "value": "TEST 123"
    },
    "jobLocation": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "address": "London, UK"
    },
    "validThrough": "2023-12-31"
}</script>
```

As you can see, the value for the name key for Organization in the hiringOrganization object is empty... so I need a way to correct this value.

I can't change the schema code directly ..so I need a way to do this by adding some HTML code after the existing schema.

Does anyone know a good way to do this? Can I change the value with a javascript? or by adding some extra schema ?

Appreciate the help!